# Pixel drawing disadvantages?

Tags: performance, graphics, drawing, pixel

Is there any disadvantage to drawing all one's graphics pixel-by-pixel, as compared to using pre-defined rectangle- or circle-drawing functions? Self-defining such functions is fine. Mainly, I'm just worried about execution speed.

---

Also, what about sprite sheets? How do they compare to all of the above?

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of issues:

1. The OS or library-supplied routines may use hardware acceleration which will be faster than what you're likely to write on your own.
2. The OS or library-supplied routines have likely been tested better than code you'll write from scratch. (It's already being used by millions of people, so if there was a bug, it probably would have been hit by now!)
3. You'll have to update your routines when hardware changes, whereas an OS or library can abstract that away. (They have to change theirs as well, but they keep the interface the same so your program keeps running.)
4. You're unlikely to write routines that are general and faster than those supplied by popular OSes and libraries since they're written by people with a lot of experience, highly optimized, and  often written in conjunction with the people who designed the hardware.

Comment: What if the pixel-drawing routine is library-supplied (hardware acceleration, cross-platform, etc.)? Also, it just occurred to me to compare all these things to bitmap/png/whatever sprites (edited above).

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you're asking. What do you mean by "pixel-drawing routine"? I assumed you meant doing the drawing yourself in your code. But if that's not what you meant, then I don't know what you mean by it, since all drawing happens at the pixel level when you get down to it. Even OpenGL has to draw the pixels that make up your textured, lighted triangles, eventually.

Comment: I'd be using SDL2's SDL_RenderDrawPoint function, so something like that. #3 sorta threw me; wasn't sure if this is what you thought I meant. I'm not very skilled with this terminology; just saw 'routine' used a couple of times above and assumed it was valid.